# Why is my Ruby RegExp not working properly?

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm writing a method where I need to exclude lines that contain this `"{"` and this `"}"` characters. I'm using the StringScanner Class with the `exists?` method. The `args` parameter is an array of strings.

```
def body_content (args)
    body_lines = []
    args.each_with_index { |x, i|
      x.reset
      if !x.exist?(Regexp.new("{")) && !x.match?(Regexp.new("^ +.*")) 
        body_lines << "Add space at the beginning of line #{i + 1}"
      elsif !x.exist?(Regexp.new("}")) && !x.match?(Regexp.new("^ +.*")) 
        body_lines << "Add space at the beginning of line #{i + 1}"
      end
    }
    body_lines
  end
```

The end result should be that my `body_lines` array should only include lines that do not contain `{` or `}` and that do not have space in the beginning. 
I'm succeeding with my second task (adding lines that do not have space in the beginning), however, I'm not being able to exclude lines that contain the curly brackets.
Am I not seeing something?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. Provide the minimal code and input to demonstrate the problem, along with your desired output.

Comment: In Ruby it's idiomatic to use literals to define patterns, rather than `Regexp.new(...)`. For instance, don't use `Regexp.new("{")`, instead use `/{/`. It reduces visual-noise.

Comment: Can you give some sample input and some sample output? The way you've expressed this here is really verbose and misleading. As The Tin Man says, this would be way shorter with things like `x.exist?(/}/)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you create a new question and the system tells you that your title is not unique or descriptive enough then please do not add something like "[Ruby]" to the end of it. That's a tag, and you have already tagged your post with ruby. I attempted to remove it from the title but the system rejects the post with this title. Please change your title to an appropriately descriptive one. You can read about titles at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Compare https://regex101.com/r/5vIhL1/3 and https://regex101.com/r/5vIhL1/4. They accomplish the same thing when checking for leading spaces but the second is less efficient and will cause the Regex engine to waste time, slowing your code if you're working on long strings or in a loop, and especially for long strings in a loop.

Comment: What about just `args.select{ |line| !line[/^\s|[{}]/] }` if `args` is a list of strings? All the rest can be removed then. See a [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/iu5Q7W).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, be cautious using `\s`. It's not a substitute for a single space as it covers all whitespace `/[ \t\r\n\f\v]/`.

Comment: @theTinMan I know, I used `\s` on purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function could look like this:

```
class MyRegExp
    def body_content (args)
        body_lines = []
        args.each_with_index { |x, i|
            puts "x is #{x}"
          if !x.match(Regexp.new("{")) && !x.match(Regexp.new("^ +.*")) 
            body_lines << "Add space at the beginning of line #{i + 1}"
          elsif !x.match(Regexp.new("}")) && !x.match(Regexp.new("^ +.*")) 
            body_lines << "Add space at the beginning of line #{i + 1}"
          end
        }
        body_lines
      end
end
```

And you can test it like this:

```
require_relative '../my_regexp'

RSpec.describe MyRegExp do
    context "with { and leading space" do
        it "should add these strings to the output" do 
            args = []
            args << " This string has a leading space"
            args << "This string contains { and }"
            args << "This string contains neither"
            res = MyRegExp.new.body_content(args)
            expect(res).to include "Add space at the beginning of line 3"
            expect(res).not_to include " This string has a leading space"
            expect(res).not_to include "This string contains { and }"
        end
    end
end
```

If I've understood what you're trying to accomplish - the tests pass:

```
➜  test_ruby_scripts rspec
x is  This string has a leading space
x is This string contains { and }
x is This string contains neither
.

Finished in 0.00231 seconds (files took 0.07841 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

You don't need this StringScanner class - I don't even know what it should do - but Ruby has built in functions to check if a string contains a RegExp.

I think this is a simplified version of your function:

```
class MyRegExp
    def body_content (args)
        body_lines = []
        args.each_with_index { |x, i|
            puts "x is #{x}"
            body_lines << "Add space at the beginning of line #{i + 1}" if !x.match(/^ +.*({|})+.*/)
        }
        body_lines
    end
end
```